# angularjs + unit test +jasmine + karma.conf.js

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm totally new in using angularjs. Recently I was asked to unit test angularjs controller with Jasmine, another unfamilier framework to me. I wrote serveral simple cases, run those stuff together in WebStorm, but the cases are always failed no matter how harder I try. And the thing frustrate me most is that they seems failed by the same reason which I can not fix :(

Here's my codes :

controller to test:

```
/*home.js*/
var app = angular.module('Application', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'Hello World!';
    $scope.user = function(){
        return {
            name:'Robin',
            age:32
        }
    }
});
```

test cases:

```
/*home.tests.js*/

describe('MainCtrl', function(){
    var scope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Application'));
    // Here $rootScope, $controller are always undefined...so the function quits before scope has been initialized.
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller){

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        $controller('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('should have scope defined', function () {
        expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have variable text = "Hello World!"', function(){
        expect(scope.text).toBe('Hello World!');
    });
});
```

karma.conf.js (part of it)

```
    files: [

      'Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
      'allScripts/angular-1.3.0/angular.min.js',
      'allScripts/angular-1.3.0/angular-mocks.js',

      'Scripts/wdso/home.js',
      'UnitTest/JsTests/home.tests.js',
    ],
```

The question seems like that the $injector is undefined all the time,  the second foreach block never runs successfully.

Now the question have taken my 2 days and just drive me crazy. I did a lot of search on net but did not found any help. Can someone kindly tell me what's wrong with my code like missing any references? Any suggestion will be welcome and much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't include the error message you got, which doesn't help. But the `Application` module you're loeding in your test  depends on the `ngResource` module, and the JS file containing this module is not listed in the `files` array of your karma config. So it can't be loaded, and the Application module depending on it can't either.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet ! That helps me indeed!! I didn't post error message together with my code due to it's a MAYA words to me...I'll remember to included them next time no matter what's they are. Anyway, I added "'allScripts/angular-1.3.0/angular-resource.js'," in my file list in my karma.conf.js as you pointed out, and now it runs normally , and now the lovely green bubble is showing!Thank you very much man!!!Plus, if I want test a controller which calls $http inside of it and will be mocked with $httpBackend , is it enough to add ngResource module as I just did ?? Thank you again!

Comment: @LiadLivnat, thanks for your response :) But they are no more showing now. Next time I'll post them as well with my example. Thank you!

Comment: ngResource is necessary to use the $resource service. $http and $httpBackend are in the core of angular. You don't need ngResource to use them.